# Bananas in cocktails or other drinks

Tags: cocktails

I have a lot of bananas at the moment - too many to consume by just eating or cooking or using in general.  What is the best way to use banana in a drink - assume that I have a fairly wide and varied bar to choose from for the base of the drink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bananas can go in any blended tropical drink fairly well.  Any strawberry drink (daiquiri or margarita) can have bananas added.  For obvious reasons though bananas would go better in a frozen drink than a "on the rocks" drink.

You can also peel bananas and freeze them and they will stay fine for a couple of months.  The flesh will darken but they are perfectly OK to use.  Take a frozen banana out and toss it into the blender for a smoothie or frozen cocktail.

In my opinion, bananas go well with the more tropical alcohols like rum, teqauila, triple sec, etc..

Comment: Although I was first to answer, this is clearly the better answer.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose this is obvious, but how about the [Banana Daiquiri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daiquiri).